# Generating Symmetric Group with Transpositions

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, finitely-generated, involutions

There is a theorem in our book which I'm trying to prove, It says:

> **Theorem**: Number of Transpositions which generate $\mathbb{S}n$ can not be lower than $n-1$.

I've  already proved that $\mathbb{S}n$ can be generated by $n-1$ Transpositions, but I don't have any Idea about to show it can not be lower than that.

Comment: If you know graph theory then this is clear. Consider a graph whose set of vertices is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. We define two vertices $i\neq j$ to be adjacent iff $(i\ j)\in X$, the generating set. Now this graph is necessarily connected, since $S_n$ is transitive. This forces the graph to have at least $n-1$ edges.

Comment: That was awesome. Thank you